# Android strange sqlite bug

Tags: android, cursor

i have an android application in which i' m using cursors and listviews. I have developed this app when running android version was 2.1. I had decide to not use StartmanagingCursor() and stopmanagingcursor() because of their instable behavior when i move from an activity to another. In fact of that i have created a static function which called on each of lifecycle events to manage activities cursors. Below is the full code of this function.

```
public static void onBegin(Object extraMethodName, Activity activity,
            Utils.lifeStatus lastStatus, Utils.lifeStatus currentStatus) {
        Method method;
        Utils.currentActivity = activity.getLocalClassName() + "_"
                + Integer.toString(activity.getTaskId());

        if (!Utils.lifecycleCheck(lastStatus, currentStatus)) {
            DBAdapter.open(activity);
            if (extraMethodName != null) {
                try {
                    method = activity.getClass().getSuperclass()
                            .getDeclaredMethod    (extraMethodName.toString());
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    method.invoke(activity);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void onEnd(Object extraMethodName, Activity activity,
            Utils.lifeStatus lastStatus, Utils.lifeStatus currentStatus) {
        Method method;
        Log.i("Utils.currentActivity", Utils.currentActivity);
        Log.i("ActivityClosing",
                activity.getLocalClassName() + "_"
                        + Integer.toString(activity.getTaskId()));
        if (Utils.lifecycleCheck(lastStatus, currentStatus)) {
            if (Utils.currentActivity.equals(activity.getLocalClassName() + "_"
                    + Integer.toString(activity.getTaskId()))) {
                if (extraMethodName != null) {
                    try {
                        method = activity.getClass().getSuperclass()
                                .getDeclaredMethod(extraMethodName.toString());
                        method.setAccessible(true);
                        method.invoke(activity);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                DBAdapter.close();
            }
        }
    }
      public static boolean lifecycleCheck(Utils.lifeStatus lastStatus,
            Utils.lifeStatus newStatus) {
        boolean result = false;

        if (lastStatus != null) {
            switch (lastStatus) {
            case PAUSE:
            case DESTROY:
            case STOP:
                result = false;
                break;
            case RESUME:
            case START:
            case RESTART:
            case ONACTIVITYRESULT:
                result = true;
                break;

            default:
                result = false;
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Where extramethod is the initialization function of each activity in onBegin function and the close cursors function in onEnd function.

Theese functions used to works perfect till i decide to create a base Activity in which i have one cursor and one adapter and all the other acivities inherits from base. This Activity also manage the lifecycle. ( Bellow the full code ). After that change i have deploy my application in android v4.0 and my customers report me that it crashes in random situations. It's extremely difficult to me to replicate the bug but i can see that when the application crashes i'm taking strange duplicate data from clients to server.

```
   package baseActivities;

public class BaseListActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected BaseCursorAdapter _cAdapter;
    protected BaseGridCursorAdapter _gridAdapter;
    protected BaseImageCursorAdapter _imageAdapter;
    protected String TAG = "BaseActivity";
    private static Utils.lifeStatus _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.DESTROY;
    public Cursor _cursor;

    public enum filterTypes{
        query,category,subcategory,promitheutis
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context cnt=this.getApplicationContext();

        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mUEHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

                Intent i = new Intent(cnt, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("ERROR", 1);

                AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) cnt
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System
                        .currentTimeMillis() + 1000,
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                cnt,
                                0,
                                i, 0));
                Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
            }
        };

       // Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUEHandler);
    }

    protected void setupForm() throws Exception {

    }

    public void search(HashMap<filterTypes,Object> FilterParams)
    {

    }

    public void openRowDetails(int position,String quantity)
    {

    }


    public void back_click(View v) throws Exception {
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Utils.onBegin("setupForm", this, _lastStatus, Utils.lifeStatus.START);
        _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.START;
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Utils.onBegin("setupForm", this, _lastStatus, Utils.lifeStatus.RESTART);
        _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.RESTART;
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestart()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Utils.onBegin("setupForm", this, _lastStatus, Utils.lifeStatus.RESUME);
        String settedLanguage = Utils.getLanguage();
        Utils.SetLaguage(settedLanguage == null ? Settings.LANGUAGE
                : settedLanguage, this.getBaseContext());
        _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.RESUME;
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Saving activity state
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be
        // "paused").
        Utils.onEnd("prepareToCloseDB", this, _lastStatus,
                Utils.lifeStatus.PAUSE);
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
        _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.PAUSE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
        setListAdapter(null);
        Utils.onEnd("prepareToCloseDB", this, _lastStatus,
                Utils.lifeStatus.STOP);
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
        _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.STOP;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // The activity is about to be destroyed.
        setListAdapter(null);
        Utils.onEnd("prepareToCloseDB", this, _lastStatus,
                Utils.lifeStatus.DESTROY);
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        _lastStatus = Utils.lifeStatus.DESTROY;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
    protected void prepareToCloseDB() {
        TextView emptyTextView = ((TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
        if(emptyTextView!=null)
        {
            emptyTextView.setText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.parakalw_perimenete));
        }
        if (_cursor != null) {
            if (!_cursor.isClosed()) {
                _cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is one of the logs that i have collect from my application.

```
-----------------EXCEPTION START--------------------
26/01/2013 15:05:58
 -----------------STAACKTRACE--------------------
 Don't have database lock!
 Class:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase | File:SQLiteDatabase.java | Method:verifyLockOwner | Line:2090
 Class:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase | File:SQLiteDatabase.java | Method:endTransaction | Line:690
 Class:myapp.myapp.FindMeetingActivity | File:FindMeetingActivity.java | Method:deleteMeeting | Line:235
 Class:myapp.myapp.FindMeetingActivity | File:FindMeetingActivity.java | Method:onContextItemSelected | Line:142
 Class:android.app.Activity | File:Activity.java | Method:onMenuItemSelected | Line:2538
 Class:com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback | File:PhoneWindow.java | Method:onMenuItemSelected | Line:3521
 Class:com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder | File:MenuBuilder.java | Method:dispatchMenuItemSelected | Line:735
 Class:com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl | File:MenuItemImpl.java | Method:invoke | Line:149
 Class:com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder | File:MenuBuilder.java | Method:performItemAction | Line:874
 Class:com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper | File:MenuDialogHelper.java | Method:onClick | Line:167
 Class:com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3 | File:AlertController.java | Method:onItemClick | Line:924
 Class:android.widget.AdapterView | File:AdapterView.java | Method:performItemClick | Line:292
 Class:android.widget.AbsListView | File:AbsListView.java | Method:performItemClick | Line:1058
 Class:android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick | File:AbsListView.java | Method:run | Line:2514
 Class:android.widget.AbsListView$1 | File:AbsListView.java | Method:run | Line:3168
 Class:android.os.Handler | File:Handler.java | Method:handleCallback | Line:605
 Class:android.os.Handler | File:Handler.java | Method:dispatchMessage | Line:92
 Class:android.os.Looper | File:Looper.java | Method:loop | Line:137
 Class:android.app.ActivityThread | File:ActivityThread.java | Method:main | Line:4444
 Class:java.lang.reflect.Method | File:Method.java | Method:invokeNative | Line:-2
 Class:java.lang.reflect.Method | File:Method.java | Method:invoke | Line:511
 Class:com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller | File:ZygoteInit.java | Method:run | Line:787
 Class:com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit | File:ZygoteInit.java | Method:main | Line:554
 Class:dalvik.system.NativeStart | File:NativeStart.java | Method:main | Line:-2
 ---------------EXCEPION END----------------------
```

May you help me to understand why is that? It caused by a problem with my base activity or it caused by a change on android v4.0.?

Thanks for our help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't have database lock! in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738834/dont-have-database-lock-in-android)

Comment: @Cthulhu  No it's not duplicate because as you can see i'm calling DBAdapter.Open() and DBAdapter.Close() when static onBegin function and onEnd() called from lifecycle events. That's what is marked as the correct answer on "Don't have database lock! in android" post.

Comment: I am also running into an sqlite problem with 4.1.2 (sqlite version 3.7.11).  After creating a row in a DB without any kind of error I am getting an error when I go to access that row later.  However, it only happens with specific column values.  I can take that same DB and read the row with Android 2.3 (sqlite 3.7.2) without problem as well as with a version of sqlite for the pc.  I don't see a workaround for this until a fixed version of sqlite gets pushed out to the 4.1 phones.