# close() was never explicitly called on database - app doesn't crash

Tags: android, database

Sometimes in my logcat the following error occurs:

> close() was never explicitly called on database
>   '/data/data/com.example.addremovelistviewsave/databases/MY_DATABASE'
>
> android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application
>   did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here ...

at : `sqlHandler = new SqlHandler(this);`

(It lies in onCreate method in an activity)

and at:  `sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

it is in :

```
public SqlHandler(Context context) {

                 dbHelper = new SqlDbHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                   DATABASE_VERSION);
                 sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                }
```

The SqlHandler is :

```
public class SqlHandler {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            Context context;
            SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase;
            SqlDbHelper dbHelper;

            public SqlHandler(Context context) {

                 dbHelper = new SqlDbHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                   DATABASE_VERSION);
                 sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                }

    public void executeQuery(String query) {
     try {

      if (sqlDatabase.isOpen()) {
       sqlDatabase.close();
      }

      sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      sqlDatabase.execSQL(query);
      sqlDatabase.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {

      System.out.println("DATABASE ERROR " + e);
     }

}

        public Cursor selectQuery(String query) {
         Cursor c1 = null;
         try {

          if (sqlDatabase.isOpen()) {
           sqlDatabase.close();

          }
          sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          c1 = sqlDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

         } catch (Exception e) {

          System.out.println("DATABASE ERROR " + e);
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return c1;

}
        public void insertValues(ContentValues cv) {
            dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert("MEM", null, cv);
            Log.e("inserted", "inserted");
        }


         public byte[] getImage(Cursor c) {
            return (c.getBlob(1));
        }



        public int deleteItem(myItems item) {
             try {
                 if (!sqlDatabase.isOpen()) {
                     sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                 }

                 return sqlDatabase.delete(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, "_id = ?", new String[]{item.getID()});

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 System.out.println("DATABASE ERROR " + e);
                 return -1;
             }
         }
}
```

I don't know where to put close (if that is the problem).
The app doesn't crash but I have  memory leaks.Is there a change the above is responsible for this?

-------------------UPDATE--------------------------------

In the code I use:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("title", mytitle);
                ...
                cv.put("imageblob", blobvalue);

                sqlHandler.insertValues(cv);
```

Now, it shows the  error at : `sqlHandler.insertValues(cv);` above

and at: `dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert("MEMORIES", null, cv);`  from insertValues function above.

Comment: close Cursor c1 before closing sqlDatabase

Comment: @vsk:Where exactly?At selectQuery? Before return c1;

Comment: You may benefit from (or enjoy) using a content provider, database utility library, or an ORM... such as: http://greendao-orm.com/, https://github.com/jeffdcamp/dbtools-android, https://github.com/yenrab, http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738834/dont-have-database-lock-in-android).

I had to add :

```
public void close() {
            sqlDatabase.close();
            dbHelper.close();
            }
```

in SqlHandler class and then  `sqlHandler.close();`

after   `sqlHandler = new SqlHandler(this);`

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you left database open. Keep the practice that open database only whenever, and wherever it is necessary. After, if you think you no further need the database related operartions, just close the database and cursors.

The error you got was because the activity you reached, found the database in opened state. Infact, this is a warning not an error.

Edit: if you don't understand where to close the database, just close the database from where you switch to other activity.

Comment: :I tried to do that.I am not sure where else I must close the database.Can you help me please?Also,is this capable for memory leak?Thanks!

Comment: Yes there are chances of memory leak. Also there are chances of SQL-Injection attacks.

Comment: :If I use : sqlDatabase.close(); after sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); (see above in post) will that be ok?

Comment: @George Yes this will be ok, but put `database.close();` after the query is executed.

Comment: @George Or else you can do is, wherever you finish the current activity, just put `database.close();` before it. Or wherever you use Intent to go to next activity, simply call `database.close();` before Intent statement. This solution also works.

Comment: :I am sorry I can't reproduce the error again!!!It seems sometimes it gives it some not!I just want to find out what the possible error is in my code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30425/discussion-between-shree202-and-george)

Comment: :Hello , if you want to see the update I have in my post at the end.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after try catch add a finally block and close the database there.

```
try{
  open database
  do database operation
} catch(Exception e){
  handle exception
} finally {
  close the database here
}
```

in your case you can do this

```
public void executeQuery(String query) {
 try {
  sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  sqlDatabase.execSQL(query);

 } catch (Exception e) {

  System.out.println("DATABASE ERROR " + e);
 } finally{
     sqlDatabase.close();
  }
```

Comment: :I am not sure where exactly I must do this.Can you check the code I have above?Thanks

Comment: :I am trying to find the error!!Sometimes it gives me the error sometimes not!!!(also, the way I have the executeQuery isn't the same?)

Comment: if there is any exception at line .. sqldatabase.execsql then your database will not be closed. SO better use finally.

Comment: :I am sorry I can't reproduce the error again!!!It seems sometimes it gives it some not!I just want to find out what the possible error is in my code above.

Comment: .. try to understand my last comment.. then you will realize when it will happen

Comment: :All the above code in my post is right?And only the executeQuery was wrong?

Comment: :Hello , can you check the update at the bottomm in my post?Now ,it gives me the error somewhere else.(I used your code above for the  executeQuery)

Comment: @ StinePike:Still the same "close() was never explicitly called on database ...".It has also " at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1827)..." (if you want them i will update)

Comment: :Yes, I told you that I have implemented your executeQuery.

Comment: :If you have any suggestions , please tell me .Thanks!